# Cocos2d games in iOS7 not hide status bar

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How to hide status bar in cocos2d iOS7 games? This problem is not observed in iOS6 and below.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden: YES];
```

What's iOS7 alternative for this ?

Answer (score 12):

Its simple...…add below line in info.plist

```
View controller-based status bar appearance  NO
```

ScreenShot:
[image]

Comment: better than  my solution !  +1

Comment: which is your solution? is there any other way to hide ?

Comment: in CCDirectorIOS.m add a method :  -(BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden{return YES;}

Comment: may be wrong plist Or its viewController based..not cocos2d

Comment: @Guru Not working for me, I have tried answer mentioned by you and also the comment by YvesLeBorg

Comment: make sure you are trying with right pch file and its cocos2d game.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem, fixed with

`- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}`

Comment: in which class you added this?

Comment: It needs to be in every UIViewController class where you want to hide status bar.