# Cannot hide status bar cocos2d iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I tried to add `View controller-based status bar appearance: NO` and `Status bar is initially hidden: YES` to plist, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationNone]` and `- (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden` to CCDirectorIOS and AppDelegate, no one works.

There's something I am missing?

Comment: make sure you added it to right plist and clean build. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134120/cocos2d-games-in-ios7-not-hide-status-bar/19134145#19134145

Comment: Yes, I already tried that, does not work. I'm using cocos2d 2.1.

Comment: Why the close people ???  does your preferStatusBarHidden method return YES ?

Comment: Yes I have that method returning YES. I found the solution, you need to set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to YES, not to NO, contrary to what is said in that answer. Apparently is only a problem in 2.1.

Answer (score 4):

Add below given function to CCDirector.m file.

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {return YES;}

Answer (score 1):

In your *Info.plist* set *Status bar is initially hidden* to *YES* and *View controller-based status bar appearance* to *NO*.

See more here: https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/279/hiding-status-bar-ccmenu-fix-ios7